# How Can I Use th:data-url

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, data-uri

I need to take the number of id from:

```
<div class="social"  th:data-url="@{http://localhost:8080/poll?id=${poll.pollId}" data-title="">
```

But this does not work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //get value of 'this' element that was clicked
  var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
  // split string and get value of id
  var splitted = url.split("id=");

  console.log("Id:"+splitted[1]);
});
```

Or bind `onclick` or `onchange` event

```
<div class="social" th:data-url="@{http://localhost:8080/poll?id=${poll.pollId}" th:onclick="'getId(\''+ ${poll.pollId} +'\')'" data-title="">
```

And get the id value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function getId(id) {
           console.log(id);
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the custom attributes are defined using `th:attr` attribute. Like:

```
<div class="social" data-title=""
  th:attr="data-url=@{|/poll?id=${poll.pollId}|}" data-title="">
```

Also specifying `@{}` with the URL or `href` will build the complete URL.